# ${project.name} lost when using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, maven, applicationcontext

I'm using Maven to build a Spring (3.0.5.RELEASE) project. In my applicationContext.xml I use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (to load properties from the DB) like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="configurationConverter"/>
</bean>
```

The properties I want to access in the DB works fine, but `${project.name}` and `${project.version}` stops working. Where do these properties come from originally? And most importantly: how can I get them back?

Comment: Those are properties that are only available during the build with maven. Those are maven specific. Those aren't available when running your application.

Comment: Are they replaced into text in my `target/` folder when building?

Comment: Is this a java project or a web project? What directory contains your applicationContext.xml file?

Comment: If you use the Maven Resources plugin and set filtering=true, then you can replace Maven variables like 'project.version'.  See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: @RichardNeish: put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Maven Resources plugin and set filtering=true, then you can replace Maven variables like 'project.version'. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html